most efficient way to create a flatlist table like the github commit
I'm trying to create a table thats like the github contributions horizontal scroll and data should go column down in order.
<ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <FlatList
            data={[...Array(100).keys()]}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <SmallHistoryBlock
                
              />
            )}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            numColumns={Math.ceil(100 / 7)}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              paddingHorizontal: 10,
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>

however if this code isnt divisible by full number, it will create a new row and add the remainder which I dont want.
Is the only way to implement this is by Creating a Flatlist inside another flatlist? I dont want to do that because preformace wise its not that efficient.
Any help would be appreciated!

First thing I see is a FlatList in a ScrollView which would cause your flat list to be rendered completely. No virtualization. So I would remove that scroll view and let the flat list scroll again. It sounds like all you want is to make sure you have a number of items divisible by your number of columns? Why not just filter the data array to a count divisible by your number of columns before passing it to the list?

@DustinForsyth if i get rind of the scrollview im not too sure how i can achieve flatlist thats rendered horizontally since numColumns is not supported horizontally

The way that I have done that is make the renderItem on the flatList be the column and then grouped all the columns into an array in the data array of the flat list. So If I wanted 4 columns I would put 4 items in an array then place that array in the data array then the renderItem would be expecting an array of 4 items that it would layout in a column. Hopefully that makes sense. Doing it that way seems like you would be able to fix the issue with having exact number of items?

@DustinForsyth Gotcha so what im understanding is that the render item is an array in an array being [number of column[number of rows]]. And since theres only 7 rows its okay to not put it in a flatlist and just use .map?

I posted an answer below with what I would do in your situation.

I think what you are looking for is something like this:
The List:
const itemsCount = 100;
const numberOfColumns = 7;

const data = [...Array(100)].reduce((dataArray, item, index) => {
  const columnIndex = Math.floor(index/numberOfColumns)

  if(!dataArray[columnIndex]) {
    //Start a new Column
    dataArray[chunkIndex] = []
  }

  dataArray[columnIndex].push(item)

  return dataArray
})

   return(
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <ColumnOfSeven
                items={item}
              />
            )}
          />
         );
}

This Column Item:
const rowOfSeven = ({items}) => {
<View>
  {items.map(item => {
    return(
      <View>
        {item.title}
      </View>
    )
  })}
</View>
}

Doing it this way still allows you to use the flatList for virtualization so you should have better performance.

Gotcha gotcha. Thanks for the help Dustin!

Yeah for sure let me know if you run into anything with this that I missed.
